# Syntax error on closing brace after opening a php tag

Tags: php

i'm getting trouble with a function that looks pretty much like this:

```
<?php 
function my_function() {

    if(!empty($variable)) {
        //Do some stuff
    }
    else {
        ?>show a message<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

The problem is i'm getting a parse error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘}’ in /www/bla/bla/bla.php on line 8

I know for a fact that i'm not missing or have an extra '}' brace because the code works just fine on my local server and i've run a validator to make sure the syntax is correct, however, when i port the code to the online server, i get the error.

I believe it has something to do with the php installation not supporting the closing and reopening of php tags between the condition but i'm not sure how would i go about fixing it.

I know i could just do echo 'message'; instead, but this is not the only place where the script uses that kind of syntax to display messages, so fixing it here would just mean i'd get the error on another line, and then another.

Thanks.

Comment: I would return a value from your function instead of doing this. Also I don't understand why you cannot use `echo 'message';`. That being said, when I try to run your code it works fine. The error must be somewhere else. If you think your php installation doesn't support this, please post some details about you php installation.

Answer (score 3):

As it stands that piece of code runs just fine as is on PHP 5.2.14.

When you pasted in the code are you sure you pasted this line exactly as-is?:

```
?>show a message<?php
```

The only thing I can think of is that the code on the server is using a short open tag `<?` but `SHORT_OPEN_TAG` is turned off in the server's `php.ini`, for example :

```
?>show a message<?
```

Comment: short_open_tag doesn't seem to be the issue. The opening tag is indeed <?php

Comment: @BioXD - it was a stab in the dark. What happens when you run from the command line?: `php <filename.php>` ?

Comment: Just had the exact issue as the OP, turns out for me it was a short tag... The code in question opened with <?php, but there was a <? earlier in the script that threw off the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue with my file.  This was throwing an error in my file:

```
<?php } ?>
```

This may seem silly, I added a comment which seemed to fix the error:

```
<?php 
  //
  }
?>
```